# Copy METADATA from Developer Edition to Scratch ORG

Tags: deployment, metadata, scratch-org

I'm trying to move the metadata from developer edition or say to Scratch ORG.
What are my options in order to do the above?

I'm thinking the following but I'm not sure if this is the best practice to do or have any better way of doing.

1. Create a Project with Manifest and in the Package.XML define all the metadata I want.
2. Create a Package in the DE org and pull the metadata ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, fundamentally, that's the start of the process for moving from Developer Edition-based development to scratch org-based development. Either (1) or (2) works fine; they're basically equivalent so it comes down to what you find easier (I generally find 2 easier).

Once you've pulled down the metadata you need (and converted it to Salesforce DX format), you'll likely need to go through an iterative process to get it to deploy cleanly into a scratch org. You'll try to deploy and get back *lots* of errors - some component will fail and then everything that depends upon it, directly or indirectly, will also fail to deploy. Your process is to find those root errors and start figuring out what you need to do:

- Did you capture some metadata you don't really want? Remove it.
- Does your metadata include references to features that you didn't mean for your package to depend on? (This is very common with Quick Actions on Page Layouts, and references to schema that is feature-dependent). Edit your metadata to remove those inadvertent dependencies.
- Do you have *real* feature dependencies that your scratch orgs aren't currently satisfying? Maybe you need Enhanced Notes turned on, or a Record Type on Account, or Person Accounts, or Shared Activities. For these you edit your scratch org definition file to enable Features or populate Settings to tailor the org's shape to match your needs.

It often takes a few rounds and some investigation to clear all the errors in that bundle of extracted metadata, but ultimately, you'll get to a point where you can deploy cleanly into a scratch org. At that point you're ready to start doing scratch org-based, source-driven development fully.

Answer (score 1):

Package based approach is easier since the handcrafting package XML can be error-prone.

You can run the command `sfdx force:source:retrieve -n MyPackageName` to retrieve everything in your package in DX Source format without having to go through unzipping of file or conversion from one format to another. Here MyPackageName is the package name, you will need to replace with your package name.

Finding Dependencies on features and Settings.

There is a view dependency button on the package that shows even feature dependencies and might be a really good way to write your scratch org features.

[image]

[image]